# The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting

Tags: github, composer-php, packagist

I don't really understand how Composer works with the minimum-stability setting.

I have two packages. Let's say, `PackageA` and `PackageB`.

The `composer.json` file of `PackageA` looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "vendor/packagea",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "vendor/packageb": "dev"
    }
}
```

So `PackageA` requires `PackageB`. The json of `PackageB` looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "vendor/packageb",
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

So both say minimum stability are `dev`. So I assume that when I do:

```
composer create-project vendor/packagea
```

But then it complains with the message:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find package vendor/packagea with stability stable.
```

Which I find strange, because I would assume that setting the minimum stability to `dev` would pull the package from its "development" branch. Which in the case of github is always `dev-master`.

So I tried to install it by telling composer what branch to use:

```
composer create-project vendor/packagea testFolder dev-master
```

But then it complains that it can't find `PackageB`:

```
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package vendor/packageb dev could not be found.
```

Then how am I able to install my package? I'm still developing so I dont want to create a release for PackageA and PackageB yet...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two issues:

In create-project, by default the command uses the stable stability to look for the package to install, that's why it works if you specify dev-master but not by default. You could however also run `composer create-project vendor/packagea -s dev`

After while installing dependencies, I'm guessing that your package does not exist in a version just called `dev`, so it can't find it if you require it like that. Requiring dev-master would probably work, like:

```
{
    "name": "vendor/packagea",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "vendor/packageb": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing the `require` to `dev-master` works indeed. Also have to install it with the `dev-master` option. But it still seems strange to me. Loos like `dev` is completely useless since it really doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: Requiring `*@dev` for example would be a valid version constraint that allows dev versions, but dev by itself means it tries to do an exact match for a version called like that, which does not exist.

Comment: won't work with composer 1.0-dev 2015-07-21: `Invalid stability provided (=dev) must be one of: stable, RC, beta, alpha, dev` must be -sdev:
`composer create-project vendor/packagea -sdev`

Answer (score 0):

How did I fix this?

After installing Composer, run the following command to install the Composer Asset Plugin:

```
php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"
```

Now choose one of the application templates to start installing Yii 2.0. An application template is a package that contains a skeleton of the Web application written in Yii.