# Cannot define a library as Dependency in my project

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a project with only 3 files of PHP code written by me and a library `phpQuyer.php`. I am trying to add

https://github.com/TobiaszCudnik/phpquery

as a dependency of my project.

But I am getting the following error as shown in my screenshot [image]

Is it because in the project on Github it does not have any `composer.json` in it?

**P.S.**

That library is not updated often.

I am trying to integrate Composer with my project because my client said this

> "the only thing I would want is composer integrated, so if I need to
>   extend with using additional libraries I can easily do that it should
>   be pretty easy to include composer as part of your package"

Comment: Maybe if we could see that composer json... however this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083045/the-package-is-not-available-in-a-stable-enough-version-according-to-your-minimu

Answer (score 1):

> Is it because in the project on Github it does not have any composer.json in it?

Yes, exactly. The project itself doesn't have a `composer.json` file and is not registered at the main Composer repository:  https://packagist.org/.

The package can not be found by Composer using the repository name nor can you find it, when using the packagist search.

---

Your options:

**Fork**

1. Fork the project. Add a `composer.json` file. Register the fork at Packagist.
2. Add the requirement for the "fork" to your project.

**Define a package**

The dependency you would like to fetch does not support Composer, but you can still can define the package yourself by using a package repository.

Referencing: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2